# Retrieve data from post meta meta_key having '_product_fq_image' while having author_id and post type is PRODUCT

Tags: posts, users, post-meta

How can we retrieve data from postmeta having '_product_fq_image' while having author_id and post type is PRODUCT

I have tried this

```
$lt_content_design= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'lt_content_design', true );
```

but how can we use JOIN here for listing only particular user data having posttype is product

Comment: First, if you want to get data from postmeta you should use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) instead of  get_user_meta. Second, do you want to get data from postmeta or do you want to get posts with a set of meta fields values?

Comment: @cybmeta, I want get data from postmeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get post meta fields, you can use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function, but obviously not `get_user_meta()`, the name of the functions are self-explanatory.

The first parameter of `get_post_meta()` function is the post ID; here you define which post you want to get postmeta from. So, you need to get frist the post ID of the post you want and then pass this ID to `get_post_meta()`.

For example, you can get the posts from author with ID 5, limit to "product" post type and then get the post meta for each found post. For example, using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

```
$args = array(
            //Get all posts from author 5 and post type "product"
            'author' => 5,
            'post_type' = 'product',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1
        );
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post) {
    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lt_content_design', true);
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! thanks a lotzzzz, +1 :)